# Getting valid data as well as Internal Server Error from AWS Web-socket API Gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement a web socket based communication using API Gateway. Going as per the docs, I have been able to make a basic communication using Lambda integration.

However, whenever I post data to the `https` URL, I receive 2 responses on my web socket.

The first message is the actual data that I had posted.
The second response is an Internal server error.

```
message received: {"statusCode":200,"body":"Received Msg :: df"}
message received: {"message":"Internal server error","connectionId":"***=","requestId":"***="}
```

My lambda function currently is very basic one as can be seen below:

```
const util = require('util');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ENDPOINT = '******.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/production/';
const apig = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({endpoint: ENDPOINT});

const sendToOne = async (id, body) => {
  try {
    await apig.postToConnection({
      'ConnectionId': id,
      'Data': Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)),
    }).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Received Msg :: ' + JSON.parse(event.body).data
    };
    sendToOne(connectionId, response);
    // callback(null, event); tried this line as well
}
```

What might be causing this second response event from the socket. Any suggestions or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed your API?

Let me know whether it's as simple as that. If you have previously done so, I can recommend alternate techniques.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the API are deployed.